# Excel posting 'old' formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I seem to have a problem with my excel table.

To make it clear, it's a table within the sheet, so not just the normal cells.

After creating a formula in a column (say for example `=A1+A2`), this is applied to the entire column. Okay, so far so good.

However I discovered an error in the formula (say `A1` needed to be changed to `C1`) and changed the formula accordingly.

Everything seems fine, but when I add rows it autofills the cells of that column with the **'old'** formula.

So instead of containing `=C1+A2` the formula `=A1+A2` appears.

The Excel error message states that the other cells are not the same as the column formula (with the green triangle at the topleft corner).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site. I was unable to duplicate this problem. What method did you use to apply the formula to the entire column? And when you say "*entire column*", do you mean the **ENTIRE** column or only to the end of the table?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and the welcome:) I create a table, add a column, and enter a formula in the top row. This causes the formula to be applied to the entire column of the table.

Comment: I also have an option to "restore the calculated formula"

Comment: When you changed the formula, didn't Excel give you the Auto-correct option again to "*Overwrite all cells in this column with this formula*"? Mine did. I used it and then when I added a row, the formula was correct.

Comment: That is true, but if you want to change it to something without a formula it doesnt give you that option.

Comment: SOLVED!!!!

I had to select the table column via the black arrow at the top of the Header. Then delete everything inside the column, this also deleted the 'saved' formula. Eventhough i didnt want to do this, I also have other data/cells in this table, I had no choice.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!! I had to select the table column via the black arrow at the Header. Then delete everything inside the column, this also deleted the 'saved' formula. Eventhough I didnt want to do this, since I also have other data/cells in this table, I had no choice.